# Sugar in custard cookie dough.

Tags: cookies

I completely forgot to add the sugar in my custard cookie dough. I've already baked them, anything I can do with them?

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/52051/69382, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/55603/69382, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/92603/69382, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/81303/69382

Answer (score 1):

you can heat up a cup of water and dissolve sugar into it until you reach a thick consistency, and put then spread or pour it over your cookies as a glaze.

Answer (score 1):

How about treating them like (U.S.) biscuits and eating them with jam?  The consistency will be different, but will probably taste fine.